# Cannot implicitly convert derived type to its base generic type -

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, properties

I am using generic in below way

```
Public Class ActionResult(Of T)

Private mResultInfo As T
Public Property ResultInfo() As T
    Get
        Return mResultInfo
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As T)
        mResultInfo = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class



Public Class AnalysisResult
   Public Property ResultFileName As String
   Public Property ResultValue As String
End Class


Public Class TestAnalysisResult
  Inherits AnalysisResult
  Public Property Score As Long
End Class

Public Function PerformAnalysis(analysisParameters As AnalysisParameters) As ActionResult(Of AnalysisResult)
  Dim actionResult As New ActionResult(Of TestAnalysisResult)
  Return actionResult ' Causing me compile time error. Cannot implicitly convert derived type to its base generic type
End Function
```

I believe derived class can be caste to base class.
But somehow above thing is not working.  I have googled and seems something related to co-variance ? 
Could anyone throw some light here ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But I think you would be better using a generic for your return value. Something like this:

```
Public Function PerformAnalysis(Of T)(analysisParameters As AnalysisParameters) As ActionResult(Of T)
    Dim actionResult As New ActionResult(Of T)
    Return actionResult
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for the reply. I am getting below error on the above statement. Value of type 'Namespace.ActionResult(Of Namespace.TestAnalysisResult)' cannot be converted to 'Namespace.ActionResult(Of Namespace.AnalysisResult)'.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks again. Your suggestion will work for me. But I would like to know the reason/fix, the above code. Could you please help me out in that also ?